# Session expiring

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to make an error session that expires after 10 seconds but using the method i followed it  just always unset the session even before the 10 seconds.

First file of action
**action.php** here is the error code for the session that i created

```
if(!$form)
{
$_SESSION['error']="L'email du contrôleur n'existe pas.";
$start_e=$_SESSION['start_e']=time();
$_SESSION['expire_e']=$_SESSION['start']+10;
header("location:../nsf-sfe.php");
}
```

and here the **page.php** where i check if the session is expired or not.

```
if($now >= $_SESSION['expire_e'])
          {
          unset($_SESSION['error']);
          }
else {
//code
}
```

Comment: sorry i found the error when i re-readed my question , It's about $_SESSION['start_e']
how can i delete the question Please ?

Comment: Just edit it. There's a button EDIT under the question.

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, then post it as an answer instead of adding the solution to the question :). And if Vicky solved your problem, then mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm new , thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

increase the time like below

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 10);
```

in place of this

```
$start_e=$_SESSION['start_e']=time();
$_SESSION['expire_e']=$_SESSION['start']+10;
```

Comment: I need to use session to move from page to other

Comment: i was just talking about the increment in time not the session value

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to write $_SESSION['start_e'] correctly and now it's okay.

so now it's like

```
if(!$form)
{
$_SESSION['error']="L'email du contrôleur n'existe pas.";
$start_e=$_SESSION['start_e']=time();
$_SESSION['expire_e']=$_SESSION['start_e']+10;
header("location:../nsf-sfe.php");
}
```

and it works.